# Protect ASP.NET application 

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

Imagine, I create an application ASP.NET MVC for a customer. This application is running an a local server of my customer (I call it customer1). Is there a way to make this application impossible to run foranother customer if customer1 give application to customer2 ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you bothering and wasting your time with things like this? Make sure you license your code, probably obfuscate it, and sell it to a customer. If he violates the license agreement and gives it to someone else that's his problem. Sue their asses and that's it, end of the story. But remember that no matter what you do they will find a way :-)

So focus on delivering a good product and customers will come by themselves to you asking you to buy it.

Comment: +1 It's generally going to be way too much time and effort to mess with this too much.

Comment: you are right, I was programming when this question come to my brain :)

Comment: Suing someone is significantly most costly and time consuming than just adding the right copy-protection in the first place. Just because copy protection can be done horribly wrong, does not mean it shouldn't be done. Plus the amount of time and effort required to even _discover_ that the project has been shared is more than it would take just to add simple _tracking_ information to the app.

Answer (score 1):

You could hardcode in a check for the domain it's running on perhaps. Simple but crude.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding some checking to application start is not a bad idea. checking Computer name and Mac address doesn't seem bad.

Answer (score 0):

1- check in your code for a value placed in a file has an encrypted data.
this file generated on windows root or some root the customer1 not know it.
this file will generate in activating through online connection or by yourself.

in runtime read file and decrypt, you may read values for expired date, some configuration you want.

you may check for as friends said for computer name, ip address anything difference customer1 from customer2

2- also you need to protect dll files from decompilation methods

My Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's a Web Application -- the easiest way is to host the application for your customer, that way they won't be able to get the source for it.

Answer (score 0):

Most applications use business rules, naming conventions, assets, etc. that are unique to their business. Hard code those values into your app so that a shared app just doesn't apply to another customer.

Beyond that, you can look into a real copy-protection package like [DeployLX](http://xheo.com/products/copy-protection), [Infralution](http://www.infralution.com) or [Desaware](http://www.desaware.com/products/licensingsystem/index.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Rhino Licensing](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-licensing/introduction).

James Gregory wrote a nice [post](http://jagregory.com/writings/rhino-licensing/) on how to get started with it.

Also the [link](http://blogs.balsamiq.com/product/2008/10/19/my-views-on-software-piracy/) to a post by Balsamiq in James' article is well worth a read.

Comment: If you are going to vote down, it would be nice to say why.  I learn nothing otherwise.